# Feature extraction for text

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am stuck at this issue and am not able to find relevant literature. Not sure, if this is coding question to begin with.

I have articles related to some disaster. I want to do a temporal classification of the text. Hereby, I want to get the sentences/ phrases related to the infoamtion before the event. I want know about classification from background in ml. But I have no idea about relevant extraction. 
I have tried tokening the words and get relevant frequencies and also tried pos tagging using max ent.

I guess the problem reduces to analyzing the manually classified text and constructing features. But I am not sure how to extract patterns using the pos tags. I also am how to know the exhaustive set if features.

Comment: Do u have an example for a sentence / phrase related to the information before the event?!

Comment: Are you looking for a temporal tagger? Like HeidelTime or SUTime?